# How to test window.addEventListener('storage', (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => { ..... })?

Tags: angular, jestjs, addeventlistener

How can I test adddEventListener?  I'm trying to simulate the addEventListener call, but I can't even mock the call with jest

```
      public checkChangeLocalStorage() {
    window.addEventListener('storage', (storageEvent: StorageEvent) => {
        this.checkAuthenticityLocalStorage(storageEvent)
    })
}
```

I tried this way:

```
    document.addEventListener = jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce((event, callback) => {
            callback()
        })

    service.checkChangeLocalStorage()
    expect(document.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

error:

```
  expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  47 |
  48 |         service.checkChangeLocalStorage()
> 49 |         expect(document.addEventListener).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
 window.addEventListener = jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementationOnce((event, callback) => {
            callback(returnMock)
        })

    service.checkChangeLocalStorage()
    expect(window.addEventListener).toBeCalledWith('storage', expect.any(Function))
```

reference: https://www.codeguru.co.in/2021/02/testing-javascript-events-with-jest.html